# Can't apply plugin at the end of android gradle file

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, module

[In this tutorial](https://medium.com/@parsaniahardik/firebase-cloud-messaging-android-studio-tutorial-65198eebf254) I found that I have to add a line at the end of gradle(Module:app) file to enable firebase cloud messaging. But when I tried to add this line at the end of gradle file it shows me some errors (below):

***Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0***

My gradle(Module:app) file is : 
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0
somehow it was old, that's why conflicting. Now solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add this in your root-level `build.gradle`:

```
'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```